# nginx и Leverage browser caching в Django

Tags: django, nginx, кэширование, gzip

Здравствуйте.

Есть необходимость кешировать данные, которые берутся с внешних ресурсов, а именно https://maps.googleapis.com/ и https://www.google-analytics.com:

Можно сделать вот так:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 24h;
    }
```

но статика приложений и медиа файлы находятся в `../static` и `../media`

и сейчас я делаю что-то вроде:

```
location /static {
        root /var/www/project/static;
        gzip            on;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types      *;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        expires         15d;
    }
```

и примерно так же для медиа

Но если же использовать первый вариант, то не срабатывает тот что с `root` и статика не подгружается.

Как правильно это реализовать ?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге конфиг получился такой:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=2:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=1G;
proxy_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/proxy 1 2;
proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;

upstream project_server {
  server unix:/var/www/project/project.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80; 
    return 301 https:example.com--90ais$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name xn------dddfnxoenlfghchl4bitc.xn--90ais;
    root /var/www/project/;
    listen 443 ssl http2;  # <-
    expires $expires;
    ssl on;  # <-
    ssl_certificate /var/www/project/certificate.crt;  # <-
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/project/private.key;  # <-

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/project-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project-error.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 10m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # <-
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://project_server;
            break;
        }
    }
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/project/static;
        etag            on;
        if_modified_since exact;
        gzip            on;
        gzip_min_length 1;
        gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types      *;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_vary       on;
        expires         15d;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
    }
 location /media {
        alias /var/www/project/media;
        etag            on;
        if_modified_since exact;
        gzip            on;
        gzip_min_length 1;
        gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types      *;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_vary       on;
        expires         15d;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
    }
    location /robots.txt {
        root /var/www/project;
    }
}
```

Но не понятно, почему [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) продолжает ругаться на `Leverage browser caching` касательно https://maps.googleapis.com/ и https://www.google-analytics.com.